# Novice, using Ruby to build a small application

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm learning Ruby right now and I got stuck, maybe you guys can help me a bit.

I want to build a small app based on Sinatra that increments a value and prints it on different requests. You go to the root page and you get 1, if you refresh the page you get 2 and so on.

I have no ideea how to get the increment to happen only on refresh

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [approach](http://gist.github.com/182364) is to detect a page refresh is:

- defining a separate "refresh" link (`/increment`)
- checking `HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL` header for:

  - `max-age=0` (for FF when using `F5` or `reload` button)
  - `no-cache` (for FF and IE when using `CTRL-F5`)

I hope this helps you to start with your app :)